# How to find/replace only numbers at the end of a row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a column of course names where I'm replacing anything that isn't in Roman Numeral at the end with one. So, for example: "**My Course 1**" should be "**My Course I**". I'm using the find/replace function. So, just find "1" replace with "I". However, when I do a find and replace, it's also finding courses like the following: "**Choose 1 Course**" or "**Choose 12 Units of Credit**" so I have to manually pick and choose which one to replace instead of just selecting replace all.

I have over 6000 items to comb through so this is very time-consuming. Is there another way to find/replace but only looking at the last 2 characters in a cell?

Is it possible at all? Through VBA?

**EDIT:**

My specific file has 4 columns if that is needed.

Course Code, Title (The one I'm searching through), Description and Credits

Comment: Can you share more about the structure of the sheet where you intend to make the changes, i.e. how is it structured? Are the numbers you want to change _always_ preceded by 'My Course' and are they _always_ the last two digits in that cell? It would not seem so by the example you provided ('**My Course 1**' and not '**My Course 01**'). Also a screenshot would probably help.

Comment: @DaveWhite I've added more info about my specific file up top. The ones I want to change will always have some sort of title before them like "How to do something 1" or "This is acting 5". Actually, I guess it only needs to be the last one as I don't think I go past 8 for Roman Numerals.

Comment: Based on the above I think @cybernetic nomad's answer covers what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula will convert the last digit to a roman numeral, if it is a number:

```
=LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1) & IFERROR(ROMAN(RIGHT(B2,1)),RIGHT(B2,1))
```

Note: If the course numbers go to `10` or higher, it won't work, though a more complex formula can be made to cover those, if needed

Comment: Perfect. This worked great.